# How to add attachments to default mail compose form in php programmatically?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add attachments to default mail compose form in php programatically, I have tried using mailto but there is no option to add attachments. Is there any other way to add attachments?

Comment: what have you tried so far, do you know how to ask question on stackoverflow, if not then read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to open my default mail composer before sending a mail along with attachment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`phpmailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library which handle also attachment

while composing the mail object you can add attachment with

```
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to open my default mail composer form before sending a mail along with attachment.

Comment: Did you give a try to the class i gave you?